# sending messages via LinkedIn API

Tags: php, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

Good afternoon, I'm trying to make a PHP application that sends messages to Linkidin. From the source data there is a username and password and a user ID to which you need to send ACoAAD-VT8sBOkDLIxA0177uoxeP081m1Mvt29c. If anyone has had experience writing such applications in other languages, please share.

I also found out that there is a post overgrown with

```
https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/voyagerMessagingDashMessengerMessages?action=createMessage
```

```
{
    "message": {
        "body": {
            "attributes": [],
            "text": "р"
        },
        "renderContentUnions": [],
        "conversationUrn": "urn:li:msg_conversation:(urn:li:fsd_profile:ACoAAD-VT8sBOkDLIxA0177uoxeP081m1Mvt29c,2-OWQyYWVlNTgtM2VjNy00NWY5LWJhYWQtYjRhODY3ZDU0NmVhXzAxMw==)",
        "originToken": "1afad75e-ed34-4dd7-a7ce-fd4999937da7"
    },
    "mailboxUrn": "urn:li:fsd_profile:ACoAAD-VT8sBOkDLIxA0177uoxeP081m1Mvt29c",
    "trackingId": "\u001aú×^í4M×§ÎýI}§",
    "dedupeByClientGeneratedToken": false
}
```

but it’s not clear how to bypass authorization

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean. Are you asking how to authenticate with the linkedIn API? Their documentation should explain how to do that. Where are you stuck? But if you want to "bypass" authorization well, 1) that shouldn't be possible unless they have a security flaw, and 2) we wouldn't help you with any hacking attempts of that sort. I'm hoping you just worded that sentence badly.

Comment: yes, perhaps I asked the question incorrectly, I can’t find scopes for sending messages via Linkedin

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify it, then. See also [ask]. When you say you "can't find" the scopes, are you saying you are unable to locate some information in the API documentation?

Comment: I hope those tokens are only "stubs", not your real tokens?